# How to avoid class.forName() in OSGi?

Tags: java, reflection, osgi

I am relatively new to OSGi and our dept. is shifting to OSGi framework. I have two bundles A and B. B depends on A so I have included it in B's manifest file as Import-Package:A.

Also, I have a certain class in A which uses reflection to access a certain class from B. 
Class in A uses class.forName(class in B). I want to get rid of this reflection as this might cause problems when I shift to OSGi framework. How can I get rid of this class.forName()?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OSGi you will want to stay away from reflection, for reasons outlined in a lot of other places.

So, your situation is that bundle `A` needs some instance of a class which resides in bundle `B`. For `A` to make sense of this instance, I will assume it has some interface that it will use to talk to the instance. Let's make this a little more concrete.

```
/Bundle A
  /ThingyInterface.class

/Bundle B
  /ThingyImplementation.class (implements ThingyInterface.class)
```

This is a regular pattern: one bundle provides an interface, the other provides the implemenatation. There are now two possible situations,

- `A` needs exactly one copy of the implementation. In that case, register the `Thingy` as a service.
- `A` needs several instances of the implementation. In that case, introduce a `ThingyFactory` in `A`, and create an implementation of that factory in `B`, which you then register as a service.

In either case, you let `B` do the actual instantiation, you have no dependency from `A` to `B`, and `B` doesn't need reflection to instantiate the objects.

In short, *services are your friend*.

Comment: I dont think it's a good idea to provide interface in one bundle and implementation in another bundle. The general use case is 
define a interface -> implement the interface in the same bundle -> provide service using interface -> Other bundle refer this service and call using interface which means interface's definition is in its classpath.

Comment: @Ivan Han -- why don't you think it's a good idea to define interfaces and implementations in separate bundles? I happen to regard it as a very good idea in most cases, and would even go so far as to call it a Best Practice.

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks!! I will explore services. Just wanted to confirm, once I register 'ThingyFactory' implementation in B as a service then I should be able to use it in bundle A, without any issues?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what services are about. There must be a good intro somewhere, but you can always read http://www.osgi.org/blog/2010/03/services.html for a good overview of why services are good for you.

Comment: @Neil,sorry that, I dont explain clearly, what I mean not a good user case is define and implement a interface in one bundle(bundle A), then implement the same interface in another bundle(bundle B).

Comment: @Neil- Your draft of OSGi book is really helpful. I got it from your website!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, two ways to create objects in Java

1. Call constructer by new
2. use reflection

So if u want to avoid reflection, you can only import class in bundle A,then new() instance(In order to do this, u need imprt B in bundle A). But as bundle B alreadys depends on A, this will cause cross-dependence which isn't allowed in OSGi. So I suggest u refactor you class to extract such code from bundle A and move to bundle B.

Comment: You forgot the most important and that happens to be the best OSGi way: dependency injection. Using declarative services and the separation @Angelo was talking about is the way to go.

Comment: @Raduk,@Angelo,@Neil, here's the problem. Take the exmaple in the question, two bundles, bundle A and bundle B. yes, service can be used if bundle A want to use some interface from bundle B. But if we want to do this, we need to add package in bundle B to "Import-Package", right? This leads to (Bundle A -> Bunle B). But the precondition is bundle B already depends on bundle A that means (Bundle B -> Bundle A), this is a dependency cycle I think

Comment: @Ivan Han -- no, services do not lead to a dependency cycle. Both the service implementer and the service consumer depend (via Import-Package) on the service interface *only*. They have no dependency on each other. The service interface should normally be in a third bundle that only exports pure APIs.

Comment: @Neil, I think we are on the same line. I understand the OSGi's service usage scenario. I thought the questioner's problem is saying he had a dependency cycle, so I suggest he to extract those part code to another bundle, just like the third bundle you mentioned,which only exports pure APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case, but it sounds like you have some spaghetti in the making. You said that Bundle B depends on A, and yet A has to load a class from B via reflection. This means that A depends on B as well. Since you cannot have B -> A -> B, you need to remove one of the dependencies.

Or perhaps you need another bundle C, which contains whatever classes are common to both A and B. Remember that OSGi is there to help you create modules with clean interfaces. If you find you are having trouble making something work with OSGi, it is probably because some abstraction is leaking or some dependency has not been well designed.

Comment: ,that's also what I suggested. But seems OSGi's service can figure out the problem